# Do germs disappear in mopped liquids and canned gases?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I had some oil and oxygen infected with zombie spores.

While trying to clean this up, I mopped the oil and on the mopped oil containers, it doesn't say that they have any zombie spores, although the oil on the floor had them.

Same thing for canned oxygen in the same area. The oxygen in the air was infected, and when pumping it into the canister filler, the building says it contains zombie spores. But after emptying the filler, the canister does not say that there are any germs in it.

Will there still be germs if this canister is emptied? Same for the mopped oil, if I use it or burn it, will the germs come back?

Answer (score 2):

I found that if I turn on the Germs Overlay (F9), the game will display the germs on the mopped liquid and on the canister.

So the germs have not disappeared, the game just doesn't display them in the normal view.

It will also display germs in the Germs tab on the bottom right when the object is selected.

[image]

[image]

[image]